# print random letters-LinkedList

Tags: java

In this program i created a `LinkedList('lettersLeft')` in which I add `Letters`('Letters' is a class).Each letter has 3 values :1)which is that letter(ie 'A'),2)the times  it appears in the game(ie '9'),3)the points you get (ie '1').Also, with  `getNextLetter()` i get the next random letter from the bag. I want to make a for loop that will print me 2 random letters from the bag with their values(ie "A,9,1 D,4,2"). This is my code(if you dont understand something ask)

**Letters_bag**:

```
public class Letters_bag {

public static final Letters A = new Letters('a', 9, 1);
public static final Letters B = new Letters('b', 2, 3);
public static final Letters C = new Letters('c', 2, 3);
public static final Letters D = new Letters('d', 4, 2);
public static final Letters E = new Letters('e', 12, 1);
public static final Letters F = new Letters('f', 2, 4);


public static final Letters[] allLetters = new Letters[] {
    Letters_bag.A,
    Letters_bag.B,
    Letters_bag.C,
    Letters_bag.D,
    Letters_bag.E,
    Letters_bag.F,

};


LinkedList<Letters> lettersLeft = new LinkedList();


public Letters_bag() {
    // add all the letters
    addLetter(A);
    addLetter(B);
    addLetter(C);
    addLetter(D);
    addLetter(E);
    addLetter(F);

}

// helper method to add the letters
private void addLetter(Letters sl) {
    for (int i=0;i<sl.getCount();i++) {
        this.lettersLeft.add(sl);
    }
}
 /**
 *Returns the next random letter from the bag.
 */
Letters getNextLetter() {
    // shuffle those letters
    Collections.shuffle(lettersLeft);
    // return a random letter
    return lettersLeft.removeFirst();
}

}
```

**Letters**:

```
public class Letters {
private char value;
private int count;
private int points;

public Letters(char value, int count, int points) {
    this.value = value;
    this.count = count;
    this.points = points;
}

public char getValue() {
    return value;
}

public int getCount() {
    return count;
}


public int getPoints() {
    return points;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like?

```
Collections.shuffle(allLetters);
for(int i=0;i<letterCount;i++)
    System.out.println(allLetters[i]);
```

Your IDE can generate a toString method for you which you can simplify. (Or write one yourself)

Comment: thanks for your answer..i am working on it..why it retuns me something like this "lettergame.Letters@190d11"?

Comment: i think that the Collections.shuffle should be Collections.shuffle(lettersLeft) besause we want the letters from the linkedList to be printed randomly.right?(and beacause  Collections.shuffle(allLetters) gives me an error message)

Comment: You get "lettergame.Letters@190d11" because the Letters class needs a .toString method.  Without that, you are getting the default toString method on Object and that is to print the class name and memory address.

Comment: @des, which is why I said you need to write a toString method. I didn't write one because I didn't want to be condescending. ;)  There is 9+ million examples on the web.